# access glue table from Athena console

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have successfully created a table in Glue. But it is not visible in Athena.

[image]

How do I access the glue table from Athena console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glue data is available in Athena by default. If not, you will see this message in Athena Console. You have to **click "there" to upgrade.**

> To use the AWS Glue Data Catalog with Amazon Athena and Amazon
> Redshift Spectrum, you must upgrade your Athena Data Catalog to the
> AWS Glue Data Catalog.Without the upgrade, tables and partitions
> created by AWS Glue cannot be queried with Amazon Athena or Redshift
> Spectrum. Click here to upgrade.